# How can I define a global $httpBackend for servicesSpec and controllersSpec in AngularJS?

Tags: testing, angularjs, httpbackend

My controller relies on a service which does http requests. 
Both controller and service tests require the httpBackend with the same data. Do you have any idea of a workaround?

Comment: Does your controller perform HTTP requests directly or does the service only?

Comment: The service only performs HTTP requests.

Comment: If the service only performs HTTP requests why does the controller test need to use `$httpBackend`?

Comment: As the controller is dependent on the service, I am required to provide an httpBackend to test the controller...

Comment: If you mock out the service, you won't need to test it in the controller test. I'll answer your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine your code looks like this:

```
angular.module('MyApp', [])
    .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, MyService) {
        $scope.doSomething = function() {
            MyService.doSomething();
        };
    })
    .service('MyService', function($http) {
        $http.get('some-url')
            .success(function(response) {
                // Handles the response
            });
    });
```

In order to unit test `MyCtrl` you need to mock out its dependencies: `$scope` and `MyService`. So in your test you can do this:

```
describe('MyCtrl', function() {
    var MyServiceMock,
        scope;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('MyApp');

        // Creates a mock (spy) for MyService
        MyServiceMock = jasmine.createSpyObj('MyService', ['doSomething']); 

        inject(function($provide) {
            // Tells Angular to use MyServiceMock instead of MyService
            $provide.value('MyService', MyServiceMock);
        });

        inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            $controller('MyCtrl', { $scope: scope });
        });
    });

    it('calls doSomething of MyService', function() {
        $scope.doSomething();
        expect(MyServiceMock.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

That way you can test `MyCtrl` without having to use an actual instance of `MyService`.

I assume you know how to write tests for `MyService` using the `$httpBackend` service, so I won't post the code for it here.

Comment: You might assume to much (at least for me).  Would you please illustrate the $httpBackend test?

Comment: @Mark0978 Hi. Have you checked the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend) on the `$httpBackend` service? There are some code examples there that might help you understand it better.

Comment: Yea, been going thru them for a couple of hours.  My service returns a promise (because it uses $http) and that promise never resolves before the test ends.  I see the $http response resolve, but never the promise my service returned.

Comment: Oops, looks like if you don't call resolve() your promise never resolves :-O.  I handled reject, but not resolve.